# Science fiction movie where people are called from a waiting room only to be killed and have aliens implanted in them

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Can anyone identify an alien/creature movie, made at least 8 years ago? I remember distinctly people in a waiting room, and when they’re called they are put into a room and killed and aliens are put inside them.

The main character used smoke to put the alien people into a trance, and mentioned that bees are hypnotized by smoke.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Possibly looking for the same film; https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/577xfd/need_help_identifying_an_alien_parasite_scifi/

Comment: David Tennant Dr. Who and the Cybermen episode?